# Rename order status from filter menu from Admin Orders list in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, backend, orders

How can I rename and add quick filters to the WooCommerce orders overview:

[image]

I've did some research but can't found a solution which I can understand as a beginner in WooCommerce. I already know how to add custom order states so I think it's also very simple because my custom states already exists.

The "Tested" one in the menu has already the name because I've renamed a WooCommerce order status to this name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To Rename "fertiggestellt" (Completed) order status in Admin Order list order statuses tab menu use the following:

```
add_filter( 'gettext', 'rename_woocommerce_order_status', 10, 3 );
add_filter( 'ngettext', 'rename_woocommerce_order_status', 10, 3 );
function rename_woocommerce_order_status( $translated, $text, $domain ) {

    if ( strpos($text, 'Completed') !== false ) {
        $translated = str_replace('Processing', 'Custom text', $text );
    }

    if ( strpos($translated, 'fertiggestellt') !== false ) {
        $translated = str_replace('fertiggestellt', 'Custom text', $translated );
    }

    return $translated;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

[image]

---

Comment: Thanks again for your help.. How can I add now the other part of my question?

Comment: Alright sir. Next question coming in a few seconds.

Comment: Yes sir. I've just wrote the important things to the new question.